# Class organization: Function internal or external

Tags: actionscript-3, class, organization

I am creating a side scrolling game in Flash (as3) and trying to keep things organized and clean.

Ive created a "Level" class that gets all the level data, player data, and creates all the terrain objects and the player object. Its starting to get messy because im handlng all of the functions for player collision checks and player movement, terrain movement, sound starting and stopping, enemies, and more, all in this class. Is this normal? Or is there a better way to organize things to keep them separate, but still allow them to interact with each other.

I have a player class, and terrain class, and enemy class and etc. but there is not much going on inside them.

Thanks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like it's time to take a look at how you can break up your level class and move some of that functionality to other classes.  What you're describing happens all the time, so don't worry - it just means it's time to reorganize a little.

You might consider taking you player collision for example, and moving that out to a Physics class.  You can set up a static function that allows you to pass in two DisplayObjects, and then tests for collisions between the two.

For sounds, you might consider a singleton class like a SoundManager, that holds onto all of your sounds in an array or dictionary, and then have your other classes play sounds through a function like `playSound(soundName:String):void` on SoundManager.

Hopefully that gives you a start.  Feel free to ask if you need more details.  It also might help if you post some of your code.  Good luck with it!

Comment: Ok cool. One question I have is this: If the Level class has a contentContainer movelclip which has the terrian and enemies inside of it, and there is a separate class called EffectsManager that adds visuals like fireMC or explosionMC, how would I get EffectsManager to add those MCs to contentContainer? Or this this wrong way to go about doing it.

Comment: EffectsManager should extend a displayobject. contentContainer.addchild(EffectsManager). Then have a function in the EffectsManager class for each effect with positioning parameters. in those functions this.addChild( someeffect )

Comment: @The_asMan Thanks for the response. What about for something like dealing with a mix of collision detection and movement. For example the player should move around the level, but be stopped when there is a wall in the way. and not move through it. This kind of scenario stumps me.

Comment: There is a plethora of information on this topic alone you need to do some research for yourself and try to figure out the best method for you and the game you are designing. here is a start http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=actionscript+player+colision&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=#hl=en&safe=off&sa=X&ei=iuAgTpLKKsfX0QHp1NijAw&ved=0CBgQvwUoAQ&q=actionscript+player+collision&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=97eede9ed711c932&biw=1680&bih=873

Comment: Also please try to keep your questions to 1 question per thread. This will allow you to focus on exactly what you are asking and get a more direct answer. The comment section isn't a good place to be asking questions as other people who have not commented on this answer will not see it at all, and I am sure you don't just want only answers from me

Answer (score 1):

Without getting too much into object-oriented design principles here, my advice would be to ask yourself "What belongs in a class named `X`".

So for example, it sounds like the `Level` class should keep track of the players, enemies, and terrain on that... well, level (perhaps map or stage might be a better name?). But it doesn't need to do all the work for those objects; many of the functions that do the work for movement, collisions, sound, etc. can be moved to those other classes. Then the `Level` becomes an orchestrator; kind of like a conductor leading the music (but not actually playing the violins, horns, etc.).

Also, it sounds like players, terrain, and enemies have quite a lot in common. For example, they all need movement and collision handling. You may be able to create a parent class (say `GameObject`) and have the `Player`, `Terrain`, and `Enemy` classes extend from that. This kind of polymorphism can be very helpful for taking care of common functionality.